# A quite efficient way to get large gaps.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I know that the method of 'factorial' can guarantee that there are arbitrarily large gaps between consecutive primes, but I have a question about this method, consider the number $$g=p_1\cdot p_2...p_n$$

then we know that $g+2$ is not a prime because it's a multiple of two, and the same thing with 3, and so on, but near the end, we would have this $$g+p_n \text{ a multiple of }p_n$$
$$g+(p_n+1) \text{ an even number }$$

so what about $g+p_n+2$, is this the last number we would have before getting a number that we're not sure whether it's composite or not? note that $p_n,p_n+1,p_n+2$ are three consecutive numbers so one of them  is divisible by $3$, but this doesn't implies that $p_n+2$ is divisible, this thing depends whether $p_n\equiv 1\pmod 3$ or not.

Comment: Is $p_1$ the first prime, $p_2$ the second prime, etc?

Comment: yes that's right @MathIsLife12

Comment: Indeed the factorial can be substituted by the primorial in that known argument, but the primorial is still BIG, so I doubt that this should be called 'efficient'.

Comment: If it helps, we know that $g+p_n$ is not divisible by $3$ for $n>2$. This is because $g$ is divisible by $3$, and $p_n$ is prime (i.e. not divisible by $3$ for $p_n\neq3$).

Comment: $g = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdots p_n$ is the $n$th primordial number and you then know for $n>2$ that none of $g+2, g+3,g+4,\ldots, g+p_n,  g+p_n+1$ are prime numbers; $g-2, g-3,g-4,\ldots, g-p_n, g-p_n-1$ are not either.  So at least $p_n$ consecutive integers are not prime.  But this is not particularly efficient: for example it tells you none of $510512$ to $510528$ to $208$ are prime and none of $510492$ to $510508$ are prime, but you get the same gap with $524$ to $540$

Comment: I didn't ask whether this is an efficient way or not, I just want to know the gap that this method guaranteed @Henry

Comment: @Yassir It is guaranteed, since there is an unlimited number of primes.  Your title says  *A quite efficient way* and a primorial method involves smaller numbers than a factorial method, but is still large

Comment: It may be that $g+p_n+2$ is prime, e.g. $(2)(3)(5)+5+2=37,$ or composite, e.g. $(2)(3)(5)(7)+7+2=219=(3)(73)$ and $(2)(3)(5)(7)(11)+11+2=2323=(23)(101).$

Comment: The problem is to find the explicit prime gap (that means the primes surrounding the gap). The record gaps upto a quite large limit are tabulated in wikipedia.

Comment: Next number we can't guarantee composite is $g+p_{n+1}$